# How to declare types for uninitialized variables in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, mypy, dynamic-typing

I'm learning to use mypy and static type checkers while practicing algorithms and data structures.

In a Binary Search Tree, a Node is initialized with no children. They are of type Node. However, it seems that None is its own object type in Python so mypy gives me an error below. Is it possible to initialize the unassigned children as type Node?

```
binary_search_tree.py:17: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "Node")
binary_search_tree.py:18: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "Node")
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Code below:

```
class Node:
    # A node has a value which is an int and two children which are nodes
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.value: int = value
        self.left: Node = None
        self.right: Node = None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because these values can be `None` at times, you should instead specify them as `Optional` types and then perform explicit `None` checks when using them so that `mypy` will know that they have a value. More information from `mypy`'s docs [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#optional-types-and-the-none-type):

```
from typing import Optional

class Node:
    # A node has a value which is an int and two children which are nodes
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.value: int = value
        self.left: Optional[Node] = None
        self.right: Optional[Node] = None
```

It is otherwise impossible to declare them as only a `Node` type if you initialize them as `None`. Another option would be to create a `NullNode` (or something similar) subclass which still has the type `Node` but signifies that there is no `Node` there:

```
class Node:
    # A node has a value which is an int and two children which are nodes
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.value: int = value
        self.left: Node = NullNode()
        self.right: Node = NullNode()

class NullNode(Node):
    pass
```

Comment: Ah thank you. Are both options reasonable or is one more standard than the other?

Comment: @user2415706 no problem. Both options are definitely reasonable, but in this case, I think `Optional` is a better option because it specifically implies that the `Node`'s children may or may not be present, and it introduces better type safety because now you have to check whether the child `is not None` before being able to use its value. Also I would argue that checking whether a variable is `None` looks cleaner than checking if it has a certain type